# How to set reply action in below nougat version like whatsapp?

Tags: java, android

Am trying to set `reply` action in `push notification` like `Whatsapp`. How to show popup window like `whatsapp` for replying in `push notification`.

**I have to open a dialog like below image when click of reply.**

[image]

Comment: Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.  FYI its an Activity with Dialog theme not a Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

*Direct reply* is available on devices with Android **N** or higher.

First, you need to build remote input, that can be passed into notification builder.

```
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_INLINE_REPLY)
    .setLabel("Response")
    .build();
```

Then you can create your notification

```
NotificationCompat.Action replyAction =
  new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_custom_icon,"Respond", respondPendingIntent)
    .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
    .build();
nofitication.addAction(replyAction);
```

Next, we need to retrieve the input. In the component started by the pending intent (e.g. an Activity or Service), the remote input is available on the Intent. The user’s input is accessed using the same key that was used when building the remote input:

```
Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
if (remoteInput != null) {
    CharSequence reply = remoteInput.getCharSequence(KEY_INLINE_REPLY);
    //do something awesome with the reply
}
```

After the reply has been entered, a progress spinner is displayed to indicate that something is happening. It is up to you to stop the spinner, once the reply has been processed. There are at least a couple of ways to handle this:
Cancel the notification by calling cancel
Re-issue the notification, and include an updated message (e.g. “Successful reply”)

You should add backwards compatibility

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    //we are running Nougat
    respondIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
    respondPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, respondIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
} else {
    //we are running a version prior to Nougat
    respondIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    respondPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, respondIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

You can check more here [Direct reply in Android N](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/notifications-direct-reply-android-nougat)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i achieved direct reply for version Nougat but am trying to do the same in lower version too.. Something like window manager..

Comment: So will anyone help how whatsapp is achieving the reply option in below nougat version.